# Spin states of two electron system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

I am unsure about why we can have 4 different wavefunctions for the spin of two electrons in a helium atom, since we could have both spin up, both spin down, or one in either state. I'm unsure what is the physical meaning of have a + in the symmetric and or - in the antisymmetric wavefunction. Also how is the S value obtained here, why is it 1/0?
Thank you [image]

Answer (score 2):

A better notation would be 
$$
\vert +\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\, ,\quad \vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\, ,\quad
\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\, ,\quad \vert -\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2
$$
with the particle label explicitly attached.  Note that the labelling matters in the sense that $\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2$ is not the same as 
$\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2$ since the former means the first particle has spin up and the second has spin down, while the latter means the first has spin down and the second has spin up.

The symmetry/antisymmetry comes from permuting the particle labels $1$ and $2$.  Permuting these labels in the $S=1$ states transforms the states back into themselves, v.g. 
$$
P_{12}\vert +\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2=\vert +\rangle_2\vert +\rangle_1=
\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle_2
$$
but permuting the labels in the $S=0$ state gives the negative of the original state:
$$
P_{12}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2-\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)= \left(\vert +\rangle_2\vert -\rangle_1-\vert -\rangle_2\vert +\rangle_1\right)=-\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2-\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)= 
$$
after reordering so that kets for particle 1 occurs before those of particle 2.

---

Edit.

The state $\vert S,m\rangle$ with 
\begin{align}
\vert 1,1\rangle &=\vert +\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\, ,\\
\vert 1,0\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2+
\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)\\
\vert 1,-1\rangle&=\vert -\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\\
\vert 0,0\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2-
\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)
\end{align}
are just rearrangements of the original state so they are eigenstates of $S^2$ with eigenvalue 
$S(S+1)$, and eigenstates of $S_z$ with eigenvalue $m$.  Thus, for instance, $\vert 1,0\rangle$ is eigenstate of $S^2$ with eigenvalue $2$ and eigenstate of $S_z$ with eigenvalue $0$.

If you start a space spanned by $4$ states, you cannot rearrange the basis so there are fewer than $4$ states after the rearrangement.  Thus, in addition to the $\vert 1,m\rangle$ state, you also need the $\vert 00\rangle$ state.

Note that all $\vert 1,m\rangle$ states are symmetric under permutation of the particle labels, where $\vert 00\rangle$ is antisymmetric.  In addition, you can reach any state in the $\vert 1,m\rangle$ set by raising or lowering with $S_\pm$, but the action of $S_\pm$ will not take you from an $\vert 1m\rangle$ to the $\vert 00\rangle$ state: in general, $S_\pm$ and $S_z$ cannot change the value of $S$.

As a final note, the operators $S_\pm$ and $S_z$ are defined through
$$
S_z= S_{1,z}+S_{2,z},\qquad S_+= S_{1,+}+S_{2,+}\qquad S_-= S_{1,-}+S_{2,-}
$$
where $S_{k,z}, S_{k,+}$ and $S_{k,-}$ act only on the ket for particle $k$.

Comment: I understood that, but I wasnt sure physical meaning of the symmetric/antisymmetric wavefunction for the electrons in different states? and How is the S value calculated?

Comment: The $S$ value comes from the eigenvalue $S(S+1)$ of the operator $S^2$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "physical meaning".  For the symmetric states the spin part of the wavefunction will be symmetric, and for the antisymmetric state the spin part will be antisymmetric w/r to permutation of the particles.

Comment: Well we know the two particles can be in four arrangements, 1up 2up, 1up 2 down, 1down 2up, 1down 2down. But how does this relate to the wavefunction? Both the |+⟩2|−⟩1−|−⟩2|+⟩1|+⟩2|−⟩1−|−⟩2|+⟩1 and |+⟩2|−⟩+|−⟩2|+⟩1|+⟩2|−⟩+|−⟩2|+⟩1 ,  indicate the particles are in opposite spin states, but what is the difference between the + and -? why do we need both of them?

Comment: @Bella I added some material which hopefully will answer your query.